# Does the weather affect the noise I make?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

For example, does rain enhance my stealth movement?
In some games (i.e. Zelda BotW) your steps are softer and all of your movement is drowned out by the sound of rain, so it's harder for monsters to hear you when sneaking up to them.

Is there a similar mechanic in *Pokemon Legends: Arceus*?

Answer (score 1):

The aggro range of wild pokemon does change with the weather (the most notable are fog, thunderstorm and snowstorm), but it's not noticeable if it's the noise or the weather itself reducing aggro range. During thunderstorm it *seems* the step noise are covered by the weather but some pokémon still notice you from quite far.